# React Array checkbox to check only one checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I have several checkbox groups on my `Component` of which only one of the should be selected. Each group has the same number of checkboxes (3 in the example), and the one selected is identified by the `checked` key inside the `data` list.

How can I handle this state?

```
class test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    const data = [
      { name: orange, checked: 2 },
      { name: apple, checked: 3 },
      { name: banana, checked: 1 }
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {data.map(items => (
          <tr>
            <td>{items.name}</td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked={true} />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" checked={false} />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" checked={false} />
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Component example]

Comment: Hi james, just wrote you a solution below, please comment and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

Try organizing your data-structure to look something like this:

```
  data: [
    { name: "orange", boxes: [1, 2, 3], selected: null },
    { name: "apple", boxes: [1, 2, 3], selected: null },
    { name: "pineapple", boxes: [1, 2, 3], selected: null }
  ]
```

That gives us a group-name, an array of values to choose from and a selected value.
We'll be manipulating that data via our component-state.

Here's a codesandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-paper-b1d4z

### Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { name: "orange", boxes: [1, 2, 3], selected: null },
        { name: "apple", boxes: [1, 2, 3], selected: null },
        { name: "pineapple", boxes: [1, 2, 3], selected: null }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleOnChange = e => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const updatedData = data.map(group => {
      if (group.name === name) {
        return {
          ...group,
          selected: group.selected === value ? null : value
        };
      } else {
        return group;
      }
    });

    this.setState({ data: updatedData }, () => console.log(this.state));
  };

  createInputGroups = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const groups = data.map(group => {
      return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div>{group.name}</div>
          <div>
            {group.boxes.map(box => {
              return (
                <input
                  onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                  type="checkbox"
                  name={group.name}
                  value={box}
                  checked={group.selected == box}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return groups;
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createInputGroups()}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Pleases excuse my CSS :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check at the `checked` option if the `value` of the checkbox is the same as the `checked` value of your `item` interface. Check this component as an example:

```
function CheckboxGroupRow({ name, checked, onUpdate }) {
  return (
    <tr className="CheckboxGroup">
      <td>{name}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={1}
          checked={checked === 1}
          onChange={e => onUpdate({ name, checked: +e.target.value })}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={2}
          checked={checked === 2}
          onChange={e => onUpdate({ name, checked: +e.target.value })}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={3}
          checked={checked === 3}
          onChange={e => onUpdate({ name, checked: +e.target.value })}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Each checkbox has a `value`, and it's checked only if the value of the `checked` variable matches to the one on the checkbox. For the `onChange` handle I have an `onUpdate` function that will be called with an updated `data` item whenever a user clicks a `checkbox`. Some logic upstream should handle the update.

Please take a look at this example build on CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/checkboxgroup-cyv4p

I hope it helps